# Web page to excel '\t' is not working as a tab separator (JSFIDDLE)

Tags: javascript, excel, tabs, clipboard

I have the situation to format the number, save to the clip-board and paste into excel application.

Have shared the code in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2vtyp2vb/1/

Tried with `'\t'`, but all columns are pasted into single cell in excel.
But If i paste into notepad and copy the same content from notepad and trying to paste in excel means its working fine.

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Damn simple ,

in css add:

```
#clip{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

while pasting in excel paste as text , using paste special.
what excel tries to do is paste it as HTML